# Rails 5: Why isn't will paginate working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I've added the gem, restarted the server.

In my index action I have:

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

I reload my view. It works.

I then drop in the pagination links:

```
<%= will_paginate @listings %>
```

I get an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):
    12: 
    13: <%= render 'shared/subscribe' %>
    14: 
    15: <%= will_paginate @listings %>
    16: <div class="content listings">
    17:   <h1>Latest<span class="meta">updated <%= time_ago_in_words(@listings.first.updated_at) %> ago</span></h1>
    18:   <% @listings.each do |listing| %>

app/views/listings/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_listings_index_html_erb___4466103937708592830_70228331044140'
```

For some reason `<%= will_paginate @listings %>` isn't working.

In the error console, I can see that the error originates from:

```
Listing.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

The full error is:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:149:in `select_for_count'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:225:in `perform_calculation'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:145:in `calculate'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:52:in `count'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:97:in `count'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:95:in `count'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:79:in `total_entries'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:135:in `block in to_a'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb:96:in `create'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/will_paginate-3.0.12/lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:133:in `to_a'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:512:in `find_take_with_limit'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:103:in `take'
from /Users/guff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:513:in `inspect'
```

Can anyone see what is going on? I'm completely confused. What is causing the error?

Comment: Are you using ActiveAdmin? Does your model have a table in your DB?

Comment: No, I'm note using ActiveAdmin and yes my model does have a table in the database.

Comment: what is the `will_paginate` gem version that you are using?

Comment: `3.0.5`! Not sure how that happened. I assumed it was the latest version. Upgrading to `3.1.7` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was using an outdated version of `will_paginate`.

The problem went away after upgrading to `3.1.7`.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the `will_paginate` gem to 3.1.7 for Rails 5.2 removed that error mentioned.